# Linear Algebra John B. Fraileigh third edition

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be eigenvectors of a linear transformation $T\colon V\to V$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Prove that, if $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$, then $v_1$ and $v_2$ are independent vectors.

Comment: This is a “problem statement” rather than a question. Please add your attempt and show where you're stuck at.

Comment: Can you get started? Do you know what "independent" means? Do you have a method for proving vectors are independent? What happens when you apply that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\lambda_1\neq \lambda_2$ and corresponding  eigenvectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent. Then $v_2=...$. 
Also 
$Tv_1=\lambda_1 v_1$ and ....